# Formula with depending picklist

Tags: formula-field, dependent-picklist

I have a child object depending on Accounts. I am using the custom "type" field in accounts an have a depending picklist called "subtype". No all "types" have assigned "subtypes".
I want to pull a formula field in the child object that shows the "subtype" value when existant, or "type" value in case it doesn't.

Any ideas?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Try the [BlankValue()](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_a_h.htm) function. It'll check if the first value is blank, and if so, return the second value.

Example:

```
BlankValue(Account__r.SubType__c, Account__r.Type__c)
```